# Installing Splunk on Godaddy server

Tags: linux, installation, godaddy, splunk

Does anyone know if it is possible to install Splunk on a Godaddy server? I've downloaded the deb file on my server using `wget` (and obviously I have ssh access) but I'm struggling to install it as apparently

> -bash: dpkg: command not found

I guess Godaddy restrict what you can do but I'd like to get this working

Thanks again

Comment: what is the output of `uname -a`? You may be using a distribution that uses RPMs instead of .debs

Comment: Linux xxxxxxxxx.secureserver.net xxxxxxxxxxxx.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Nov 9 13:34:42 EST 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their website, you can have a virtual server with either CentOS or Fedora.
Or a dedicated server which includes both options from virtual + Ubuntu.

Unless you have a dedicated server with them, you can only be using a RHEL like OS, which does not use Debian files.

In this case you would require a rpm package, or could try to install it via yum, the package manager for CentOS and Fedora.

Comment: Ah ok, I can get the rpm. Will have a go at that, thanks. I don't have a dedi so that's probably it!